# Listeners not being updated in Firestore

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying the new Firestore. I had a system with the Realtime Database working fine but the new features that allows Firestore made switch from Realtime to Firestore before releasing. I managed to migrate most of it, but I'm getting errors due to the fact that the listeners do not listen to new changes, and the changes take longer to be received in the database.

EDITED

Example: I publish an article, and this article needs to be reviewed before publishing, so it's in an "articlesUser" collection in a document with a field "status" and value "pending". When I as an admin publish the article, the status goes from "pending" to "approved". What happens is that if I click on Edit, the status on this new view is still "pending".

Sample code:

```
getAllByUser(uid, limitToLast): Observable<any> {

const items$ = this.afs.collection(`countries/${this.countryDbName}/articlesUser/${uid}`, ref =>
ref.orderBy('createdAt').limit(limitToLast)).valueChanges();
...
```

where "this.afs" is an instance of AngularFirestore. The items later on are stored on the state using Ngrx Store.

When I update the articlesUser, I update other tables, so I use a batch, with the "set" method, (from the Firebase functions):

```
const batch = dbs.batch();
batch.set(dbs.collection(`countries/${country}/articlesUser/${uid}`).doc(article.key), listing);
...
```

I only allow to click on the EDIT button when the state is Accepted, but when I click on it and goes to the Edit View, the "document" loaded this time still has the status "pending". So it had the status "accepted" in a view because it let me click on Edit, but in the new view still has the "pending" status.

Is there a need to "push notifications to all listeners" function or something with Firestore?

Comment: you can complete with more information ?, show the code a little, where you retrieve your document

Comment: Hi Diego. Is it possible for you to try creating a small example of what you are trying to accomplish with stackblitz? Here is a link for the official angularfire2 stackblitz template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1iment With this I would be happy to take a look at the code and see if I can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it might have been a [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/odCVVxU2ppw/Aoj8t8UVAgAJ), but currently it works fine in my case.

I created a sample app (you have to fill up firebase credentials in app.module to make it work) that reproduces something similar to what I tried to achieve: change the "status" field and update it everywhere. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwxwjj)